# Finding sound frequency for constructive interference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, frequency, wavelength

So I got the results from a physics exam, and one question everyone in the class got wrong, so I'd like some help figuring out where I went wrong.

[image: The problem in question]

What I did was set up the observer 0.80m to the right of center, resulting in a 5.0m/2.45m/5.57m triangle on the left and 5.0m/0.85m/5.07m triangle to the right between the observer and each speaker. To find the required wavelength I multiplied the difference between the two hypotenuses by two (since the difference should be half a wavelength to go from destructive to constructive interference).

My result was a wavelength of 1.0m.

To find the frequency, I took the speed of sound (which I took as given at 340m/s from another problem's given speed in the exam) and divided it by the wavelength. Since the wavelength was 1.0m, I got 340hz. This was marked as wrong.

Can someone help me understand what went wrong here? Much thanks ahead of time.

Edit: I'm wondering if it's a rounding/significant figures issue. Before rounding, the wavelength it's 0.9927m. Dividing 340m/s by the wavelength gives 342.50, but since one of the original dimensions is 5.0m, I'm limited to two significant figures at the end, so that would still be 340hz. Ugh, he may just be nit-picking that because it's "not clear" that it's two. May just need to write 3.4 x 10^2 hz to make him happy.

Comment: What's the answer given because I think you have done it right

Comment: He hasn't given the answer. We have the opportunity to get 1/3 of the missed points if we bring back all correct answers in a few days, but since nobody got it right and we all got the same (or very similar) answers, I'm looking elsewhere to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: It looks good to me.  Could be significant figures.  Could also be a different speed of sound, although I don't know what else you could have done.  I think he may have done it wrong.  Bring him your analysis with pictures.

Comment: I think you should stay with your answer because it has the right steps as well as the answer is close if not right

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the professor was using 0.84m off center when he calculated his answer, that is, he did it wrong and I did it right. Gave me full points for it in the end. Thanks for the help everyone, it gave me confidence to look for an error on his end walking in today!

Comment: Well you were brave enough to challenge him XD

Answer (score -1):

Your error, as far as I can see, is when you multiply the difference by 2. Since there is constructive interference, the difference must be a whole wavelength.

Comment: My thinking was that since the interference is destructive when the observer is equidistant from each speaker, they should be opposite phase, and so a difference of half a wavelength puts them back in phase. Is that wrong?

Comment: @El_Snago You are correct.  This answer is wrong.

Comment: The sound travels 5.07m from speaker A, and 5.57m from speaker B. There is constructive interference at that point, i.e. they are in phase. This means that (5.57 - 5.07) = n * wavelength, and n =1 since this is the first maxima.

Comment: You write ... (since the difference should be half a wavelength to go from destructive to constructive interference) ... It should be: ... (since the difference should CHANGE BY half a wavelength to go from destructive to constructive interference)... The difference is already half a wavelength in the middle. (The speakers are of opposite phase since there is destructive interference in the middle.) Moving to the side it increases by half a wavelength to a whole wavelength.